# visual studio How do I run a windows 2008 ce Solution on VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-8

I am trying to run a VS 2008 solution built on windows 08 CE on VS 2017 but am running into multiple issues.

Upon loading the solution into VS 2017, VS attempts to upgrade the project and skips many core CE files (such as 'Elektra_SDK (ARMV4I) and 'AMC_V2_Design (ARMV4I)' ) and than gives me the "Load Failed" message next to my  **most** of the projects in the solution, stating that
"file.vcxproj : error  : Cannot load project: project does not contain configurations and no active configuration is specified.".
From looking at Microsoft's suggestions, it seems it should be easier to run in VS 2010. I tried to load this solution in VS 2010 and got similar error for **every **project in the solution of...

```
Conversion Report - FC5100App\FC5100App.vcproj: 
Converting project file 'C:\FC5100App\FC5100App\FC5100App\FC5100App.vcproj'. 
Failed to upgrade platform 'Elektra_SDK (ARMV4I)'. Please make sure you have it installed under '%vctargetspath%\platforms\Elektra_SDK (ARMV4I)' 
Failed to upgrade 'Debug|Elektra_SDK (ARMV4I)'. Please make sure you have the corresponding platform installed under '%vctargetspath%\platforms\Elektra_SDK (ARMV4I)' 
The project configuration dimension name/value "(Platform, Win32)" was not found in the project manifest. 
Project upgrade failed.
```

Any ideas on how to fix these errors and run this project?